# Finicity API Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, api

We are using the finicity API to get statements and transaction. We have followed below steps, but we are getting "aggregationStatusCode:185" while fetching the customer accounts [ https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v1/customers/['customer_id']/accounts ].

1. To get the custommer account I am using https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v1/customers/['customer_id']/accounts.
2. Then we are fetching statements for account using "https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v1/customers/['customer_id']/accounts/['account_id']/statement?index=1; this loops for 6 times. We need 6 months statement for each account.
3. Then, we are fetching transaction for account using "https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v1/customers/['customer_id']/accounts/['account_id']/transactions?fromDate=".$from."&toDate=".strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))."&limit=".$transactionLimit."&includePending=true";

We are facing the below two issues.
1. Getting timeout error, when selecting more than 2 accounts.
2. Getting "aggregationStatusCode:185" for some live accounts.

Below are the code for reference.

```
function get_statements(){

   $FinicityAppToken=$_POST['FinicityAppToken'];    
   $customerId=$_POST['customerId'];    
   $leadId=$_POST['leadId'];
   $finicityConnectUrl=$_POST['finicityConnectUrl'];

   $NoOFStatements = 6;
   $transactionLimit = 100;
   $transactionsMonth = 1;  

    $url="https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v1/customers/".$customerId."/accounts"; 
    $response=callAPI('POST', $url,false,$FinicityAppToken);

    $response = json_decode($response); 

    $allstatements=array();
    if($response){
           if(isset($response->accounts)){
              $accounts = array();
              $array = array();

              foreach($response->accounts as $account){

                if ($account->aggregationStatusCode == 0 && $account->aggregationSuccessDate != '' && $account->aggregationAttemptDate != '') {

                        for($i=1;$i<=$NoOFStatements;$i++) {
                             $url="https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v1/customers/".$customerId."/accounts/".$account->id."/statement?index=".$i;
                             $stateresponse=callAPI('GET', $url,false,$FinicityAppToken);
                             $temp = array();
                             $temp['accountId'] = $account->id;
                             $temp['statement'] = base64_encode($stateresponse);
                             $statements[]=$temp;
                        }

                      $act = array();
                      $month = date('m') - $transactionsMonth;
                      $from = strtotime(date('Y').'-'.$month.'-1');               
                      $url="https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v1/customers/".$customerId."/accounts/".$account->id."/transactions?fromDate=".$from."&toDate=".strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))."&limit=".$transactionLimit."&includePending=true";

                      $data['url'] = $url;
                      $transactions = json_decode(callAPI('GET', $url,false,$FinicityAppToken));

                      $act['account']['accountNumber'] = $account->number;
                      unset($account->number);

                      $act['account']['currencySymbol'] = $account->currency;
                      unset($account->currency);

                      if(empty((array) $account->detail)) {
                         $account->detail = (object) transactionsDetailsEmpty();
                      }  

                     $act['account'] = json_decode(json_encode($account), true);

                      if(isset($transactions->transactions)) {
                         $act['transactions'] = $transactions->transactions;

                      } else {
                        $act['transactions'] = array();                 
                      }
                    // echo "step"; 
                      $accounts[] = $act;

                } else {

                         $data['success'] = 1;
                         $data['response']=$response ;
                         $data['finicityConnectUrl'] = $finicityConnectUrl;
                         $data['leadId'] = $leadId;
                         $data['FinicityAppToken'] = $FinicityAppToken;
                         $data['customerId'] = $customerId;
                         echo json_encode($data); 
                         die(); 
                }

                $j++;

              }

              $array['accounts'] = $accounts;
              $array['leadId'] = $leadId;

              $data['accounts'] = $array;   

              $url="https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v1/customers/".$customerId; 
              $response=callAPI('DELETE', $url,false,$FinicityAppToken);      
           }
       }   

}
```

Comment: If you're searching for Finicity error codes, you will see that 185 is "One of your security questions (e.g. name of your first pet) has expired and needs to be answered." . More info here : https://community.finicity.com/s/article/201750879-Error-and-Aggregation-Status-Codes

Comment: Thanks for reply!
In case of this 185 error code occurs we have refresh the process we are getting the security question screen by finicity but its work for test account not for the live account. In live account we get 185 in response everytime
Please suggest

Comment: @AkashPagare did you able to resolve that issue. We are facing the same issue. We reconnect with bank account answer the security question but nothing happens. Keep getting the 185 error